# How do I save ajax json response to global variable for reuse

Tags: javascript, php

How can i save JSON response to a global variable in JavaScript/jQuery to be used later. I have tried several methods including saving the response text (data.responseText) returned from the call but at the end it is still empty/undefined.
I know saving the response in a DOM element is strongly discouraged.I don't want to make the same call every time i need i need that particular data. Is there no easy way of accessing it outside the ajax success call back function?

What I tried:

```
$('#pay-now').click(function(e){ 
e.preventDefault(); 
data = '';
var myResponse;
var orderObj = {
addr_id: addr_id,
cust_email:  cust_email,
total_amt_to_pay: total_amt_to_pay,
items_bought: items_bought,
shipping: shipping,
coupon_code: coupon,
trx_id: trx_id

};
// Send the data to save using post
var posting = $.post( '../inc/payment/pay_with_card.php', orderObj );

posting.done(function( data ) {
/* check result from the attempt */
data = data;
console.log(data);
payWithPaystack(data);
});
posting.fail(function( data ) { /* and if it failed... */ });
//}
});

function payWithPaystack(data){

var handler = PaystackPop.setup({

key: '<?php //echo PAYSTACK_PUBLIC_KEY; ?>',



email: data.email,
amount: data.price,
metadata: {
cartid: data.sessionId,
orderid: data.sessionId,
custom_fields: [
{
display_name: "Paid on",
variable_name: "paid_on",
value: 'Website'
},
{
display_name: "Paid via",
variable_name: "paid_via",
value: 'Inline Popup'
}
]
},
callback: function(response){
// post to server to verify transaction before giving value
var verifying = $.get( '/verify.php?reference=' + response.reference);
verifying.done(function( data ) { /* give value saved in data */ });
},
onClose: function(){
alert('Click "Pay now" to retry payment.');
}
});
handler.openIframe();
}
```

Comment: Just declare a global `var globalData` outside any function, and store it there. Will retain until the user refresh de page or navigate out. This: `data = data` don't work because it should be a different name, and should be declared outside the function.

Comment: @ariel, could you please demonstrate using the code above? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare it outside any function:

```
var dataStore;

$('#pay-now').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  //...

  posting.done(function(data) {
    dataStore = data;
    //...
  }

  //...

});
```